# Is it possible to style this avatar (img) only within the outer widget class?

Tags: html, css

Here is a snippet of HTML code (it is extracted from a WordPress Widget output in the sidebar):

```
<section id="bsp_activity_widget-5" class="widget animation-video-sidebar widget_display_topics">
    <span class="bsp-la-title">
    <h2 class="widget-title"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inbox"></i>Latest 
    Forum Activity</h2>
    </span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="bsp-la-reply-topic-title" href="xxx">Why are extra meeting dates shown in the Midweek Editor?</a>
            <div class="bsp-activity-author">
                <span class="bsp-la-text">topic by</span>
                <span class="bsp-la-topic-author topic-author">
                    <a class="bbp-author-link" href="xxx" title="View Mr Happy's profile">
                    <span class="bbp-author-avatar"><img alt="" class="avatar avatar-14 photo" height="14" src="xxx" srcset="xxx" width="14"></span>
                    <span class="bbp-author-name">Mr Happy</span></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bsp-activity-freshness">
                <span class="bsp-la-freshness">8 hours, 42 minutes ago</span>
            </div>
            <div class="bsp-activity-forum">
                <span class="bsp-la-text">in </span>
                <a class="bsp-la-forum-title bbp-forum-title" href="xxx">Midweek Editor</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I am specifically interested in this element:

```
<img alt="" class="avatar avatar-14 photo" height="14" src="xxx" srcset="xxx" width="14">
```

I see it has 3 classes associated with it:

- `avatar`
- `avatar-14`
- `photo`

I want to do some styling with css and I am concerned about using these generic class names to isolate the element because the avatar is used on other pages in different paces.

I see higher up the chain this class:

- `widget_display_topics`

Is there any way to isolate my avatar class as a descendent of `widget_display_topics` so that I only style the `img` in this widget only and no other part of the site?

Comment: so, in short, you want a separate class for the image without adding a new class to it ?

Comment: @yasirjafar Ideally yes but this is the output of a widget so I don't have control over the HTML it is creating.

Comment: Open the dev tools find the element you want to style, Right Click => Copy => Copy Selector, It should give you a selector specific to that page layout which in theory shouldn't affect other pages as long as the layout is different

Comment: @AndrewTruckle There are different ways you can select and style the element one way is like .elementClass > .someinnerclass. > .moreInnerclass and then to be more specific add a child parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestand you right, you want to target that specific element with CSS without affecting similar elements with similar classes?

Try using the following CSS selector:

```css
.widget_display_topics img.avatar.photo
```